# How to increase the size of a card on hover in react

Tags: reactjs

There is grid which contains cards .On hover of a card I want to increase the height of the card in-order to show extra information.This is happening.but issue is ,card pushes other cards down of the another row.How to avoid this.

Below is the code sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/muddy-darkness-in78p?file=/src/styles.css:634-763

Comment: What's the expected behaviour?
How will you show extra information without pushing other cards down?
Do you mean it should just overlap over other cards?

Comment: yes overlapping over other cards.

Comment: Let me know if this works : https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-dijkstra-ng3r1
I'll post an answer if it works for you.

Comment: I don't find any changes you made in sandbox

Comment: Did you find the expected behaviour?
Or you are talking about the code?

Comment: talking about the code .and design remain same

Comment: Very weird, I made the changes and I can also see the change.

Comment: but the lower card is shifting to top